# Check through selected items in CheckedListBox and show/ hide columns based on values selected

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, checkedlistbox, datagridviewcolumn

I am using C# and I need some help. I have DataGridView that I would like to filter (show/ hide columns) based on user selection from the CheckedListBox.
Inside the CheckedListBox, I have listed few items and those are the Column Names from the DataGridView:
All these columns are hidden by default.
[CheckedListBox items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O01Wq.jpg)

Now if user selects THERMAL, I would like to show THERMAL Column in DataGridView. If user deselects THERMAL, I would like to hide THERMAL Column in DataGridView. If user selects/ deselects multiple items, I would like to show/ hide all those items from the DataGridView. I hope this makes sense.

Here is the code that I have:

```
private void CLB_SHOW_HIDE_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string col = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < CLB_SHOW_HIDE.CheckedItems.Count; i++)
    {
        if (col == "")
        {
            col = CLB_SHOW_HIDE.GetItemText(CLB_SHOW_HIDE.CheckedItems[i]);
            this.DGV_FEATURE.Columns[col].Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            col += ", " + CLB_SHOW_HIDE.GetItemText(CLB_SHOW_HIDE.CheckedItems[i]);
            this.DGV_FEATURE.Columns[col].Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the problem... If I remove else statement, I can show All the columns properly only if I go from the bottom up (see my picture above). If I go from top to the bottom, only first item would show. Then I would have to deselect that item and select another one in order for it to show.

If I add else statement like in above code, I get this
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyXvr.jpg)

Can anyone shed some light on this please?

Comment: In your else block `col += ", " + ` does not make sense. Why would you want to concatenate column names and then use that to find a column in the DataGridView

Comment: True... That makes no sense.. I should focus on first part of the code to show columns when selected and with my code, only works when I go from bottom up but not the other way around?

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out... For anyone that might look for solution similar to this, here is the code:

```
private void CLB_SHOW_HIDE_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int f = 0;
        string qry = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < CLB_SHOW_HIDE.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            if (CLB_SHOW_HIDE.GetItemChecked(i))
            {
                if (f == 1)
                {
                    qry = CLB_SHOW_HIDE.Items[i].ToString();
                    this.DGV_FEATURE.Columns[qry].Visible = true;
                }
                if (f == 0)
                {
                    qry = CLB_SHOW_HIDE.Items[i].ToString();
                    f = 1;
                    this.DGV_FEATURE.Columns[qry].Visible = true;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                qry = CLB_SHOW_HIDE.Items[i].ToString();
                this.DGV_FEATURE.Columns[qry].Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [`ItemCheck`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.itemcheck(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

For example, let's say, you have added some columns to `DataGridView`. Then you can setup `checkedListBox` and add column names to it. Also add an event handler to handle `ItemCheck` event:

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in dataGridView1.Columns)
    checkedListBox1.Items.Add(c.Name);
checkedListBox1.ItemCheck += CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck;
```

Then handle `ItemCheck` event to show or hide columns:

```
private void CheckedListBox1_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e)
{
    var item = checkedListBox1.GetItemText(checkedListBox1.Items[e.Index]);
    dataGridView1.Columns[item].Visible = e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: Probably you have fixed the problem using the solution which you shared here. But I suggest to change the solution to what I shared in this post. You also should know `SelectedIndexChanged` will raise by selecting an item while users need to put checkmark near the item. `Checking` an item is totally different from `Selecting`. By selection the item get highlighted blue, while it may be not checked.